# Sublime navigate between different file groups

Tags: sublimetext2

I have split my sublime window vertically to be able to view two files at once. In the explorer window, placed in the left side, it shows two groups, Group 1 which hold "file1" and Group 2 which holds "file2".

Is there a shortcut to change between these two files something like Ctrl + Tab (which only works with files from the current group) ? It's very frustrating to use Ctrl + 0 to point to the side bar and choose with Up Down and Enter.

I'm using Sublime Text 2.

Thanks in advance.

**FIX**
Actually I've created my own navigator shortcut. In Sublime Text, open Preferences -> Key Bindings - User and added:

```
[
  { "keys": ["alt+left"], "command": "prev_view"},
  { "keys": ["alt+right"], "command": "next_view"}
]
```

See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215334/sublime-text-2-how-to-page-up-down-without-moving-the-cursor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page-up</kbd> && <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page-down</kbd>.

I use these to navigate.